# Should I use openCV for image processing in c++?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Do you recommend using `OpenCV` for doing *image processing* using `C++`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by image processing.

If you are talking about changing the image; like compressing it or resizing it, then no not at all. I would use imagemagick.

If you want to analyze images; like trying to see if they contain something like a face, or a hand. Generally speaking open CV is great for teaching the computer how to see something.

Comment: Such image processing operations I'm interested in are `edge detection` and `feature extraction`, do you think `OpenCV` is suitable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is the best image processing library for c++.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We use it for our tracking tool [SwisTrack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swistrack/), and it works fine! However, if you want to do rapid prototyping of your algorithms, I would suggest to use Matlab. It's usually faster at early stage of development (but the performance is of course not as good as a clean C++ implementation using OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, but you shoudl also take a look at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), [IVT](http://ivt.sourceforge.net/)